# Confused by GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES causing Access Denied for database 'mysql'

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.6

I thought I understood grants in mysql, but this particular problem has me stumped.

I am logged in as the 'dbadmin' user on a mysql 5.6.27 database.

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for dbadmin@10.%                                                                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT PROCESS, SHOW DATABASES, SHOW VIEW, CREATE USER ON *.* TO 'dbadmin'@'10.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%_pt`.* TO 'dbadmin'@'10.%'                                                                               |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`db` TO 'dbadmin'@'10.%'                                                                                   |
| GRANT SELECT ON `mysql`.`user` TO 'dbadmin'@'10.%'                                                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also have a 'DEF@localhost' user

```
mysql> show grants for 'DEF'@'localhost';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for DEF@localhost                                                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'DEF'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<secret>'                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This 'dbadmin' user has the Grant_priv, but not the Super_priv. The 'DEF' user has neither.

```
mysql> SELECT user,host,Grant_priv,Super_priv FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| user             | host      | Grant_priv | Super_priv |
+------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| dbadmin          | 10.%      | Y          | N          |
| DEF              | localhost | N          | N          |
| DEF              | %.        | N          | N          |
| ...              | ...       | ...        | ...        |
+------------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

When logged in from a remote 10.% host as the 'dbadmin' user, I would expect the following command to work, but instead I get an Access Denied for database 'mysql'. I am not sure why this is happening.

````
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `mydb_pt`.* TO 'DEF'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'dbadmin'@'10.%' to database 'mysql'```
````

Answer (score 1):

You only have `SELECT` privilege on `mysql.user` and `mysql.db`.

You need to have more than that. If you could be granted

```
GRANT UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE on mysql.user TO 'dbadmin'@'10.%';
GRANT UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE on mysql.db TO 'dbadmin'@'10.%';
```

This will allow you to `CREATE USER` as it must be able to write to those two tables.

With you current grants on `mysql.user` and `mysql.db`, you cannot create any user.

Comment: I am confused. The 'DEF'@'localhost' user already exists, so I'm not sure I understand why I would need permissions to CREATE USER here. And the dbadmin user also has the 'WITH GRANT OPTION' privilege. I think I may be missing something obvious with regards to permissions for modifying mysql.user and mysql.db.